# How do you find the missing angle on irregular triangles? (Example provided)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Here is an example from my textbook:

[image: Picture taken from my textbook]

I have no idea what to do to answer this question. I know how to find the missing angles in norman triangles but I have no idea what to do here.

Comment: Use that the sum of the internal angles of a triangle is $180º$, that opposite angles are equal and straight angle are $180º$

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of angle chasing:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

At first, the angle against 75° is 75 too (works for every angle which are opposite to each other). The value of the sum of all angles in triangle is 180°. I think with these information, you should be able to complete your problem.

Comment: So for the first triangle the angles would be 75, 45 and 60. Which that means that the next triangle's angles are 52, 68 and 60. Am I doing this right? And what is the 79 for?

Comment: Yes, you are right about the first one. The next one: one of the angles is 180-60-79=41°. And then you use again information that the sum of all angles in triangle is 180, so 180-41-68=71°. And finally, your missing angle is 180-71=79°. I am not sure how you get your results of the second triangle.

Comment: Ahh, okay thanks. I thought the 60 was moved to the second triangle as well.

Comment: No no, this works only for opposite angles. These are not, but i guess it´s kind of misleading picture....glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

So, obviously, the lower left angle in the left triangle is $75°$ and the upper one in the same triangle is $45°$ because the two are opposite angles to the ones given. Because the sum of all angles in the left triangle must be $180°$, the lower right angle there must be $60°$.

This $60°$-angle, together with the $79°$ one, adds up to $180°$ with the lower left angle in the right triangle, so that one is equal to $41°$. Finally, because all the angles in the right triangle must add up to $180°$, the lower right angle in this triangle is $71°$.

That last angle is complementary to the unknown one which is why your answer of $109°$ follows immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The external angle obtained by producing a side equals sum of opposite angles. The exercise attempts to apply this mostly while angle chasing.

Vertically opposite angles are anyhow equal. 
So external angle ( all in degrees)  $= 45+75$ that includes $79$. And when excluded $ 45+75-79 =41$.

To find external angle once again by same angle addition

$$41+68= 109.$$